# Accessing public resources of an Android library that has dependencies on other libraries is producing warning that those resources are marked private

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I created a library for Android that itself is dependent on the `appcompat` and the `design` support libraries. I have marked all of my library's resources as private by placing a dummy resource in my library's `Public.xml`:

```
<public name="string_res_that_does_not_exist" type="string"/>
```

When I import my library to another project, Android Studio is producing warnings in lines that were using public resources from the `appcompat` and `design` libraries, such as:

- `?colorPrimary`
- `?colorPrimaryDark`
- `?colorAccent`
- `?selectableItemBackground`

The warning says `The resource @attr/<resource-name> is marked as private in <my-library-name>`.

This issue seems related to my problem:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183120

> The root cause here is that when a library depends on another library, it imports all the resources from any libraries it depends on into its own declared R.txt (in the AAR file). However, it doesn't include the public.txt declaration from those dependencies, so now it ends up exposing these symbols as declared but not public -- e.g. private.

How can I prevent these warnings from showing so that other users of my library don't encounter these problems?

Comment: Does this issue still exist? I haven’t run into it with the newest AndroidStudio and Gradle plugin. Do you _need_ to mark those `String`  resources as private? If they aren’t “super top secret” then it shouldn’t be a problem, make sure to name those string resources with your library as a prefix, so it’s clear to the client where the strings are coming from. Also if they’re “super top secret” that _need_ to be `private` then don’t declare them as `String` resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `String` values private to your library project you *could* do something like this:

**Ex:**

```
// This annotation will restrict everything in this class to the library project.
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY)
public final class MyPrivateStrings
{
    public static final String SUPER_SECRET_STRING = "I wet my pants in the 6th grade,"
                   + "this information can’t escape the library!";

    private MyPrivateStrings()
    {

    }
}
```

**Edit:** This might not be the *exact* answer that OP is looking for, because they say they to keep their `Strings` in their app’s resources dir. But hopefully someone will find this useful, as it is a viable solution to the main problem here.

Comment: The person asking the question was asking about resources (mylib/src/main/res/values/strings.xml) not about Strings in Java code.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska, very true! I wanted to give a different approach to the problem, because as we know, there are different solutions to the same/similar problem. Also, this might’ve helped someone else if not OP. But thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

2021

I believe now if you set the flag:

`android.nonTransitiveRClass=true`

inside your `gradle.properties` file, this will stop resources from libraries you depend on being available through your library.

aka: if the end user wants support library resources, they need to depend on the support library